# How to prevent spacing between content and back button in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, padding, back

The whole question is in the title. The 'United Kingdom' header should be at the top, but instead it is place away from the back button.

[image: The spacing]

The worst part is, when I then go onto the 'Diamond-Encrusted Ring' page, it creates a *new* back button and even *more* spacing. I would prefer no spacing and to get rid of the 'Locations' back button once on the second page.

[image: The spacing on the second page]

Answer (score 0):

You use `NavigationView` only in the root `View`. So remove `NavigationView` from the views where this behavior is happening.

Comment: So this works but now when i click onto the UK page from the Locations page, it starts slightly scrolled down so that the header is at the very top of the page, in line with the back button. Then when i go onto the diamond ring page and back, it looks normal.

Comment: Try using `.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)`

Comment: 'Reference to member 'large' cannot be resolved without a contextual type'?? Edit: I fixed the error but it still has the same problem it did in my first comment